# solar irradiance (ghi,dhi,dni) data as the in pvlib.forecast(GFS, NAM, RAP, HRRR, and the NDFD)

Tags: pvlib

As  the current pvlib.forecast is removed, how I can access the same forecasting data  of GFS, NAM, RAP, HRRR, and the NDFD with same format as in pvlib!looking for solar irradiance data(ghi,dhi,dni)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, these functionaly was deprecated in 0.9.1.

Please check the [deprecated explanation page](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/forecasts.html) :

It is recommanded to use the [Solar Forecast Arbiter](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/forecasts.html) Core library instead.